# Escape some special strings from a string, but not all of them in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a little code-editor projet on my own, in Javascript, HTML and CSS, and I was wondering if there is any way to escape special chars form certains string, but not all. I know that's not very clear, but I will try to explain :

I am reading from a contenteditable iframe the user input which can be, for example, the following string :

```
<p>This is an example string</p>
```

And I want to display exactly this string in a webpage, but I want to add some design before. Here, I would like to add a special color to the `<p>` tags. The approach I currently have is to surround those tags with a `<span>` for example, like so :

```
<span class="tag"><p></span>This is an example string<span class="tag"></p></span>
```

In Javascript, the `<span>` will be stored like so :

```
var tagopen = "<span class='tag'>";
var tagclose = "</span>";
```

So after getting the tags from the string, I would have a javascript line looking like :

```
doc.body.innerHTML = tagopen + encodeURI("<p>") + tagclose + encodeURI("This is an example string") + tagopen + encodeURI("</p>") + tagclose;
```

Is my approach correct, and if so, how can I make the body of my iframe accept HTML  char, since it looks like it doesn't now :
[image: The current iframe body seems not to accept HTML tags...]

**EDIT :**

Just to be a little bit more clear, this is the result I would like to achieve :

[image: This is the kind of result I want]

Comment: Why not just use dom methods to add the class directly to the `<p>`?

Comment: I don't want the effect to be applied to the entire string, but just on the "<p>" strings

Comment: well with jquery that's pretty easy and quick `$('p').map(function(obj){ $(obj).html(encodeURI($(obj).text()))  });`

Comment: @serdar.sanri Thanks for your help, but with your solution my whole text will be colored. I just want the tags to be colored, and I want the "<p>" and "</p>" to escape but not the "<span>"

Comment: oh..you are trying to do a syntax highlighter? If not the resultant html is invalid

Comment: thats exactly what I am trying to do @charlietfl

Comment: So what you really want is html entities instead of what `encodeURI("<p>")` produces?

Comment: To be honest I was still believing an hour ago that the escape() method from Javascript was still relevant, but it seems that it's not the case.
You would like this string to be converted in something like &lt;p&gt;

Comment: try doing `"<p>".replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>','&gt;')`

Comment: I will try it @charlietfl, thanks a lot ! Any idea of why the iframe body doesn't accept tags currently ?

Comment: not really...create a demo that reproduces it

Comment: Actually `contenteditable="true"` in your iframe works as 'what you see is what you get', So you can take its content with innerHTML and you won't need to encode < and >.

Comment: Okay @Anarion, but I would like the sytnax highlither to work "in real time", meaning that as soon as a tag is detected, the span is added and its colors is changed.

Comment: Not good idea :) You take a look at this guy https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html I have no elegant lightweight solution here

Comment: Thanks for your advice